# Limit of an integral over [0,1]

Tags: measure-theory

Let $g_n(x):= g(nx),$ where $g \in \mathbb{C^\infty(\mathbb{R})}$, $g'(x) \geq 0$, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Also, $$
g(x)=
\begin{cases}
1, x \geq 1\\
0, x \leq 0\\
\end{cases}
$$

Show that for any integrable function $f \geq 0$ $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{1}g_n(x) f(x)dx = \int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx$$

Check whether the result applies for $f(x)= x\sin^2(1/x).$

**My Approach**

I figured out that values of $g(x)$ are not defined for $0 \lt x \lt 1$, and so as $g_n(x).$ So, for any $x$ in $(0,1)$, $nx \geq 1$ if $1/n \lt x \lt 1$, that give $$g_n(x)=1, \text{ if } 1/n \lt x \lt 1, \text{ for all } n \geq2$$

Then $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{1}g_n(x) f(x)dx = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\int_{1/n}^{1}f(x)dx =\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx$$

Is my approach correct?
Any help and suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You correctly notice that $g_n(x)=1$ on $[1/n,1]$. To make your argument more rigorous try to argue that $g_n(x)f(x)$ converges pointwise to $f(x)$ on $(0,1]$ and at the same time $0\leq g_n(x)f(x)\leq f(x)\in L^1$. Can you now use a convergence result from measure theory to conclude?

Comment: Do I need to use monotone convergence theorem?

Comment: Maybe, but first you need to check if the sequence $g_n(x)f(x)$ is increasing. However, the conditions I mention in my answer, namely pointwise convergence and existence of a dominating function, which is integrable (in our case $f$ itself) suggest the dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: If $f$ is not greater than equal to zero, and $f$ is integrable, then also the result holds true(the prove I presented). Right?

Comment: You are right, positivity of $f$ is not an issue, integrability is the key. If you can argue the integral equalities (especially the first one), then yes, the argument is correct. But where in your argument do you use the properties of $g$? You say $g$ is not defined on $(0,1)$, this is not true. It is defined there and it is increasing from $0$ to $1$. We just do not know the exact values of $g$ on the interval.